# i want to add an animation to the div with @keyframes. I have tried basically everything i know

Tags: javascript, animation

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.moveUp{background-color:red; width:40px;height:40px;margin:auto;margin-top:3em;}'
var moveUp = document.querySelectorAll('.moveUp')
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style)
```

//Html

```
 <body>
    <div class="moveUp"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

i want the div to move down 200px them come up again

Answer (score 1):

You can change the style.innerHTML to the following:

```
style.innerHTML = '.moveUp{background-color:red; width:40px;height:40px;margin:auto;margin-top:3em;animation: moveDown 1s;}@keyframes moveDown{50% {transform: translateY(200px);}100%{transform: translateY(0);}}'
```

For easier readability:

```
.moveUp {
  background-color: red; 
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 3em;
  animation: moveDown 1s;
}

@keyframes moveDown {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(200px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```js
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.moveUp{background-color:red; width:40px;height:40px;margin:auto;margin-top:3em;animation: moveDown 1s;}@keyframes moveDown{50% {transform: translateY(200px);}100%{transform: translateY(0);}}'
var moveUp = document.querySelectorAll('.moveUp')
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style)
```

```html
<div class="moveUp"></div>
```

Comment: is there a way i can just do it all in js?

Comment: There are some JS animation libraries (GreenSock for example), but for the use case you described above, it is a bit overkill